# Return undefined when using reduce

Tags: javascript, reduce

Consider the following array:

```
const books = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'A song of ice and fire',
    genre: 'Fantasy',
    author: {
      name: 'George R. R. Martin',
      birthYear: 1948,
    },
    releaseYear: 1991,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'The lord of the rings',
    genre: 'Fantasy',
    author: {
      name: 'J. R. R. Tolkien',
      birthYear: 1892,
    },
    releaseYear: 1954,
  },
  {
];
```

Suppose I want to print the book with the longest title. The following works:

```
const longestBook = () => {
  const longestName = books.reduce((accumulator, book) => {
      if (book.name.length > accumulator.name.length) {
        return book;
      }
      return accumulator;
    });
  return longestName
}

console.log(longestBook().name);
```

My question is, why can't I return book.name / accumulator.name directly instead of using .name only when calling the function? If I try to do so, the result is undefined.

```
const longestBook = () => {
  const longestName = books.reduce((accumulator, book) => {
      if (book.name.length > accumulator.name.length) {
        return book.name;
      }
      return accumulator.name;
    });
  return longestName
}

console.log(longestBook());
```

Comment: Another alternative is to do `Array.from( books ).sort( ( x, y ) => y.name.length - x.name.length ) )[0]` - though that runs in `O(n log n)` instead of `O(n)`.

Comment: FYI you could get the result you want by using `return longestName.name` inside the function. I'd probably rename it to `longestBookName()` or similar though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `reduce`, you're passing along a single value - the accumulator - from the previous iteration to the current iteration. In decently-structured reduce callbacks, the accumulator should usually stay the same shape throughout the loop, so that logic can be performed on it predictably and consistenly.

If you try to return the `.name` only, there are problems:

```
  const longestName = books.reduce((accumulator, book) => {
      if (book.name.length > accumulator.name.length) {
        return book.name;
      }
      return accumulator.name;
    });
```

because

- Because you did not provide an initial value, the accumulator for the first iteration will be the first book *object*
- Inside the first iteration, you return a `.name` from either the first book object or the second book object. The name is a string, so this results in the accumulator being a string for the second iteration
- In the second iteration, the accumulator is now a string - not a book object - so `return accumulator.name` does not return anything.

Answer (score 2):

If the accumulator becomes the `.name` property, it will be a plain string and no longer have a `.name` property to compare in the next iteration.

You'd need to be consistent with your accumulator type from the very start by providing an initial value. An empty string would suffice...

```js
return books.reduce(
  (acc, { name }) => name.length > acc ? name : acc,  
  "" // initial value
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll be accumulating a string instead of an object, so you're entire `reduce()` method needs to be geared towards that.

That also means you'll need to provide an initial value for `reduce()`. By default it takes the first value of the array, which is an object, and not a string.

```js
const books = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'A song of ice and fire',
  genre: 'Fantasy',
  author: {
    name: 'George R. R. Martin',
    birthYear: 1948,
  },
  releaseYear: 1991,
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'The lord of the rings',
  genre: 'Fantasy',
  author: {
    name: 'J. R. R. Tolkien',
    birthYear: 1892,
  },
  releaseYear: 1954,
}];


const longestBook = () => {
  const longestName = books.reduce((accumulator, { name }) => {
    if (name.length > accumulator.length) {
      return name;
    }
    return accumulator;
  }, '');
  return longestName;
}

console.log(longestBook());
```